# vscode fails to start with Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/snap/code'

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, haskell-snap-framework

For a couple of days, my Visual Studio Code fails to start. Starting with `code --verbose` produces:

```
$ code --verbose
(process:9711): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:14.336: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
(code:9711): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:14.353: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(code:9711): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:14.353: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(code:9711): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:14.353: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
[9711:1016/165614.456088:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(276)] inotify_init() failed: Too many open files (24)
Failed to watch /home/falko/.config/Code/User for changes using fs.watch() (Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/home/falko/.config/Code/User')
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.582Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.582Z] from: /snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.582Z] args: { _: [], verbose: true, diff: undefined }
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.584Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.584Z] Resolved machine identifier: aa83b26b19696e7dcb8a342740bd0a02c994ea16ca0bfc477cb434d622f2df6e (trueMachineId: undefined)
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.603Z] update#setState idle
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.604Z] telemetry/optInStatus { optIn: true }
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.604Z] telemetry/machineIdFallback { usingFallbackGuid: false }
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.605Z] Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch '/snap/code'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:164:26)
    at Object.watch (original-fs.js:1232:11)
    at new g (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:391:55)
    at h._createInstance (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:252:51)
    at h._createServiceInstance (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:254:51)
    at h._createServiceInstanceWithOwner (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:253:661)
    at h._createAndCacheServiceInstance (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:253:336)
    at h._getOrCreateServiceInstance (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:252:559)
    at Object.get (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:251:129)
    at t.openFirstWindow (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:527:871)
    at c.invokeFunction.e (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:523:709)
    at h.invokeFunction (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:251:263)
    at t.startup (/snap/code/18/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:523:686)
[main 2019-10-16T14:56:14.605Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Currently, I'm on 1.39.2 installed via SNAP on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Maybe your question fits better on superuser, or askubunutu? Stackoverflow is more for programming questions. Anyway, I have the same problem. I posted it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260565/visual-studio-code-fails-at-startup-with-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-wa).

Answer (score 0):

You can run `locate gtk.css` and find where those files are:

Then you can comment out using command like:

```
sudo sed -i -E 's~^.*child-displacement-.*$~/* \0 */~g' /usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-3.20/gtk.css
```

For me, I also needed to run:

```
sudo sed -i -E 's~^.*-GtkScrolledWindow-scrollbars-within-bevel.*$~/* \0 */~g' /usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-3.20/gtk.css
```